# How to move water in iphone cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create an application very similar to [iBeer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3MfQIswl3k) I want to fill iphone from virtual water and can shake it so it produce bubbles? I tried to search any similar example of code as I am very new to cocos2d but I can't. I wanna know how can I do this? Any helpful links? Do I have to use chipmunk or anything else?

Thanks 
Mani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos 2D mainly serves to display sprites particules and otehr visual effects

The actual physics of it are handled by Chipmunk.

chipmunk is not so much a fluid engine but given enough small objects you can aproximate something like iBeer.

I remember seeing a video demo of chipmunk that did it.

I'm never did something close to that with chipmunk but try asking on the offcial forum

http://www.slembcke.net/forums/viewforum.php?f=1

they helped me out a lot and the author of chipmunk (scott) is very reactive and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response man. But is there something you can give me similar to ibeer? any tutorial ? links?

Answer (score 0):

[This explanation of animated water](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/animated-water/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to move the water like iBeer from bottom to top animation not sea animation.

Answer (score 0):

thats the use of accelerometer and you affine transform your views